# What are the known large cardinal axioms for which weaker and stronger set theories "catch up"?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, proof-theory, cardinal-characteristics

I will clarify what I mean by the title in the following four ways:

For which cardinals $\kappa$ do we have that ZFC-(Powerset axiom)+$\exists\kappa$ is equiconsistent with ZFC? If that is not possible, for which cardinals $\kappa$ is the former theory stronger proof-theoretically, and what is the "weakest" cardinal axiom that can be taken so that that is the case?

Alternatively, for which cardinal axioms or axiom schema $A$ do we have that ZFC-(Powerset axiom)+$A$ is equiconsistent with ZFC+$A$? Is that even possible?

Alternatively, for which cardinals $\kappa$ do we have that CZF+$\exists\kappa$ or KP+$\exists\kappa$ is equiconsistent with ZF? If that is not possible, what is the "weakest" cardinal axiom that can be taken so that the former is stronger consistency or proof-theoretically-wise?

Are there cardinal axioms $A$ for which KP+$A$ or CZF+$A$ are as strong as ZFC-(Powerset axiom)+$A$? How about ZF+$A$?

Comment: I don't know about CZF, but for KP and ZFC-powerset the answer will be essentially never. This is because ZFC proves various reflection principles - for any finite collection of formulas, there is going to be some set satisfying these formulas. KP is implied by a finitely axiomatizable fragment of ZFC, so ZFC+T always implies Con(KP+T). For ZFC-powerset, in many cases we can instead pick $H_\kappa$ still satisfying T, and if $\kappa$ is regular, it will satisfy ZFC-powerset.

Comment: For CZF this kind of question is really going to depend on how you formalize the large cardinal axiom in question. Classically equivalent formulations of axioms are frequently not intuitionistically equivalent.

Comment: @JamesHanson I would expect that to be the case for ZFC-powerset too. My proposed idea works for "local" definitions, in the sense of saying that if $\kappa$ has a large cardinal property, then it also does in $H_\lambda$ for some $\lambda$. But for more "global" definitions like using correctness or elementary embedding definitions the answer might be different.